# Android App slow Loading for unity Artoolkit

Tags: unity-game-engine, artoolkit

I am using 30 NFT markers/images and 30 3d models for a project on Unity and Artoolkit. The Android App loading as become very slow. It takes about 50 seconds to load the Camera.

Initially, the Splash Image loads for 15-17 seconds and then there is a black screen which stays for about 34-36 seconds. After that the camera starts.

I have used multiple techniques like Texture Compression, Audio compression, etc which were provided, this helped to reduce apk size to 58MB but still loading is a problem.

Please find attached the logs after build:

- Textures       15.4 mb    24.0%
- Meshes         8.4 mb     13.1%
- Animations    34.0 mb     52.8%
- Sounds        516.2 kb    0.8%
- Shaders       606.4 kb    0.9%
- Other Assets  139.8 kb    0.2%
- Levels        637.3 kb    1.0%
- Scripts       665.1 kb    1.0%
- Included DLLs 3.9 mb  6.1%
- File headers  62.2 kb     0.1%
- Complete size 64.4 mb     100.0%

I am not sure what is causing the problem.

Comment: hey buddy, this info is still insufficient for us to help you. when did the problem start occurring? In your case I would test things one by one like - remove audios and build, does it still take too long? remove the 3d models, build, still too long? ... so on until you find what's causing the problem. Then again, why are you using unity 4.7? update to the latest if you can mate.

Comment: I am using Unity 5.5. I followed the same way, when I remove audio there is little improvement but when I remove the 3d models (along with their texture), the app loading becomes very fast. So, I guess 30 NFT markers/3d-Models is causing a problem. It is not possible to reduce the 3d model so will need help with other ideas to do so